# p:fileDownload in p:dataTable does not work (just refreshes page) after performing search on the p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, download

I have a JSF/PrimeFaces web application. In one page `<p:dataTable>` and `<p:fileDownload>` components are been used. The bean constructor loads the data from the DB. It works fine when the page loads. The download button is provided in the last column of the datatable. When this button is clicked, then it is going to file download controller and everything works fine.

But if I add a search function to the page which filters the datatable results based on the query, then clicking the download button doesn't return the downloaded file, instead it just refreshes the page.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: To exclude the obvious, is your bean been placed in the view scope?

Comment: right now my bean in request scoped ,is it wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if the model behind the `value` of the `<p:dataTable>` has incompatibly changed between the request of displaying the table with the search results and the request of downloading the file. That can in turn happen if your bean is request scoped. The model is then newly created on every single HTTP request. During the form submit request, JSF needs to iterate over the model while finding and executing actions in the datatable. However, if the model does not represent the same model as it was when the form is displayed, then this will all fail.

Placing the bean in the view scope should fix the problem, provided that you're properly initializing the model in the (post)constructor and changing it in the (action)listener methods and thus *not* in any getter method. A view scoped bean instance lives as long as you're postbacking to the same view and hence the model isn't reinitialized on every request anymore, but just the same one will be reused across requests on the same view.

Or, if you really need to keep the bean in the request scope for technical reasons, then you need to ensure that you pass the search query as request parameter as well, so that the model can properly be initialized based on the search query.